# Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client Start error. Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-4.5, ngrok

I am using SignalR from Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client in a client WPF C# application. The SignalR host is a ASP.NET MVC web app where the SignalR Hub is created from Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR. Both projects are using .NET4.5.2

I use a port mapping tool called **ngrok** from **ngrok.com** to create external URLs that point to my local Visual Studio 2019 development environment.

I have 2 accounts with ngrok. One for my personal testing and another for a client. Both URLs point to my development environment with the exact same config with the exception of the AuthToken/LicenseKey. The problem I am facing is that when the WPF client is using my personal **ngrok** account to start a connection to SignalR, all is perfect. But when I change the URL to use the clients **ngrok** account, SignalR fails to start the connection with the following error...

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
> the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted:
> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.    at
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
> ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I have searched the web and tried a number of suggestions (Not just specific to SignalR but the "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error in general) and nothing has worked. I.e. in my hosts Startup.cs ...

> ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

> ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender,
> cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

Both URLs use https and have a valid wildcard cert issued to **ngrok** by R3. The SignalR host is also a website. Using either URL, the website responds and serves up pages and the lock icon is visible in the URL address bar of the browser (I use Chrome).

So I am at a loss as to why SignalR fails when I use my clients **ngrok** URL but works fine with my personal one. Can anyone help please? It would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your options.

```
            HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl($"{baseUrl}{hubName}",
                options =>
                {
                    options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = message =>
                    {
                        if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                        {
                            // bypass SSL certificate
                            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
                        }

                        return message;
                    };
                })
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();
```